# How do I add more than two conditions ?Eg: if , if , else

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>abcd</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="vote()">click</button>
<script>
function vote(){
  var age,voteable;
  age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
  if (age > 120){
      voteable = "not alive";
    }
  else{
        voteable = ( age < 18) ? "Too young" : "Old enough";
  }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = voteable;
}
</script>
<input id="age" value="age"/>
</body>
```

Here, I have only two conditions. If and else.I want to add another condition, if the input isn't a number.How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

> ```
> if (condition1)
>   statement1
> else if (condition2)
>   statement2
> else if (condition3)
>   statement3
> ...
> else
>   statementN
> ```

(You can, of course, replace any of the statements with a block containing multiple statements).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `else if`

```
<script>
function vote(){
  var age,voteable;
  age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
  if (age > 120){
      voteable = "not alive";
  } else if (age >= 18) {
      voteable = "Old enough";
  } else {
        voteable = "Too young";
  }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = voteable;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```js
if (age > 120){
  voteable = "not alive";
}
else if(age < 0){
  voteable = "Not born yet";
}
else {
  voteable = ( age < 18) ? "Too young" : "Old enough";
}
```

The above would be the same as:

```js
if (age > 120) {
  voteable = "not alive";
}
else {
  if(age < 0) {
    voteable = "Not born yet";
  }
  else {
    voteable = ( age < 18) ? "Too young" : "Old enough";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than 2 conditionals to check you may use one of the following:

#### If-else-if

```js
if (condition1)
  statement1
else if (condition2)
  statement2
else if (condition3)
  statement3
...
else
  statementN
```

Example

```js
if (x > 50) {
  /* do something */
} else if (x > 5) {
  /* do something */
} else {
  /* do something */
}
```

or

#### Switch case

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches valueN
    [break;]
  [default:
    //Statements executed when none of
    //the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]]
}
```

Example

```js
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
    console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
    break;
  case 'Cherries':
    console.log('Cherries are $3.00 a pound.');
    break;
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound.');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Sorry, we are out of ' + expr + '.');
}
```